# round to precision value based on another column pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(123, 2897402, 43.25, 2),
(124, 2897402, 49.11, 0),
(125, 2897402, 43.25, 2), 
(126, 2897402, 48.75, 0)]
, ['model_id','lab_test_id','summary_measure_value','reading_precision'])
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|model_id|lab_test_id|summary_measure_value|reading_precision|reading_value|
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|     123|    2897402|                43.25|                2|        43.25|
|     124|    2897402|                49.11|                1|         49.1|
|     125|    2897402|                43.25|                2|        43.25|
|     126|    2897402|                48.75|                0|         49.0|
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

I have tried like below

```
df1 = df.withColumn("reading_value", f.round(f.col("summary_measure_value"), f.col("reading_precision")))
```

I am getting `Column is not iterable` error.

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: Your expected results does not match your sample data i.e. `49.11` in your expected results is not in your sample df

Comment: @ggordon Updated the data to match the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `round` function has the following signature:

```scala
def round(e: Column, scale: Int): Column
```

Therefore you can only round columns with a fixed precision determined in the driver.

To solve that, you could use a UDF, but in pyspark, they are extremely expensive. Python is very slow compared to native spark code.

Therefore, you could build a custom rounding function using `round` and `pow` like this:

```py
# This is not a UDF, just a construction based on spark functions
def round(column, precision):
    return f.round(column * pow(10, precision)) / f.pow(10, precision)

df.withColumn("reading_value", round(f.col("summary_measure_value"), f.col("reading_precision")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using a `udf` that uses python's built in round function to achieve this eg:

```py
@f.udf
def udf_round(value,precision):
    try:
        precision = int(precision)
        value = float(value)
        # use python built-in round function to round values
        return round(value,precision)
    except:
        # decide what to return when you encounter bad data
        # in this example I've returned the original value
        return value

df=df.withColumn("reading_value",udf_round( f.col("summary_measure_value"),f.col("reading_precision") ))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Outputs:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|model_id|lab_test_id|summary_measure_value|reading_precision|reading_value|
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|123     |2897402    |43.25                |2                |43.25        |
|124     |2897402    |49.25                |0                |49.0         |
|125     |2897402    |43.25                |2                |43.25        |
|126     |2897402    |48.75                |0                |49.0         |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine but a small question why can't we achieve this without using a `UDF` and also why I am unable to achieve the output by using `f.round`

Comment: @nmr The current implementation for round expects a number as the second parameter, you may read more [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.round.html). You could also try `df.withColumn(
    "reading_value",
    ( 
        F.floor((F.col("summary_measure_value") * F.pow(10,F.col("reading_precision")) ) + 0.49) / F.pow(10,F.col("reading_precision"))
    )
)` even though the udf is simpler